# Java Applet - List error

Tags: java, list, applet, awt

OK so I'm doing an ArrayList into a (awt) List and I'm getting the following errors when compiling.

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\DanJavaGen\ArrayList_INV.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor List(java.lang.Object[])
location: class java.awt.List
        list = new java.awt.List(arr.toArray());
               ^
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\DanJavaGen\ArrayList_INV.java:50: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getSelectedValue()
location: class java.awt.List
       System.out.println("You have selected: " + list.getSelectedValue());
                                                      ^
2 errors
```

code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayList_INV extends JApplet implements MouseListener {

public static String newline;
public static java.awt.List list;
int gold = 123;

    public void init() {



ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("Hatchet");
arr.add("Sword");
arr.add("Shield");
arr.add(gold + " Gold");
System.out.println("You have " + arr.size() + " items in your inventory.");
showInventory(arr);



        list = new java.awt.List(arr.toArray());

        add(list);

        list.addMouseListener(this);

        list.setVisible(true);

    }

public static void showInventory (ArrayList<String> theList) {
for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
System.out.println(theList.get(i));
}
}


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

       System.out.println("You have selected: " + list.getSelectedValue());
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

/**
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    }**/
}
```

What is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as [Java cannot find symbol in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269599/java-cannot-find-symbol-in-list/3269798#3269798)

There are two issues at play here:

**java.awt.List** does not have a constructor that takes **Object[]**:

```
list = new List();
for (String item : arr) {
    list.add(item);
}
```

**java.awt.List** has **getSelectedItem()** not **getSelectedValue()**:

You could your ArrayList with List as follows:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    Object index = list.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("You have selected: " + index);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see my error now. By the way, do AWT Lists take kind to detect double clicks? I looked and it needs a ListModule which does not take well with Lists. :\

Comment: if(e.getClickCount() == 2) :-D

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API docs for `java.awt.List`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/List.html), there is no public constructor that accepts an array (line 29 in your code). You can use the no argument constructor and add your items one by one using the [`add()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/List.html#add(java.lang.String)) method.

Additionally, you have a typo in a method name on line 50: It's [`getSelectedItem()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/List.html#getSelectedItem()), not `getSelectedValue()`.